# Numerical solution system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-value

I want to solve the following system of ODEs with four boundary conditions:

```
OdeM = 1/2*sigma*J1''[x] + ((a0*delta)/a1 - a1*x)* J1'[x] - (epsilon - 1)/theta*(1 + curlyphi)* J2[x] - delta*J1[x] == -2*x;
OdeP = 1/2*sigma*J2''[x] + ((a0*delta)/a1 - a1*x)*J2'[x] - J1[x] == -2*lambda*(a0 + a1*x);
Ic1 = J1[xhat] == 0;
Ic2 = J1'[xhat] == 0;
Ic3 = J2[xhat] == (2*theta)/((epsilon - 1) (1 + curlyphi))* xhat;
Ic4 = J2'[xhat] == (2*theta)/((epsilon - 1) (1 + curlyphi));
```

I parametrise the problem as follows:

```
delta = 2/100;
theta = 3/2;
epsilon = 6;
curlyphi = 1;
xi = 5/1000;
lambda = 1/2;
sigma = (20/100)^2;
muA = 1/100;
sigmaA = 10/100;
rn = delta + muA - sigmaA^2;
em = (delta*theta - Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi)])/(2*theta);
ep = (delta*theta + Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi)])/(2*theta);
a1 = (-delta*theta + Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi)])/(2*theta);
a0 = -((xi + rn - 1/2*sigma - sigmaA*Sqrt[sigma])/(delta + a1))*a1;
a = (-delta*theta + Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*lambda*(epsilon - 1)^2*(1 + curlyphi)^2])/( 2*lambda*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi));
xhat = a0/(a - a1);
```

The numerical solution is given by:

```
Sol = NDSolve[{OdeM, OdeP, Ic1, Ic2, Ic3, Ic4}, {J1[x], J2[x]}, {x, -0.3, xhat}]
```

Why is the first initial condition not respected by the solution?

```
SolJ1[x_] = J1[x] /. Sol[[1]]
SolJ1[xhat]
```

This returns:

> -0.00823872

I get this error but I am not sure it is the issue:

> NDSolve::icres: NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero
> residual for the differential system, but some components are
> different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied,
> giving explicit initial values to all dependent variables is
> recommended.

Comment: Two second order equations need four initial condtions. The second equatioan  is  solved Its value at x=0 contradicts the initial value for the first. probably.  You can check it.

Comment: I indeed have four boundary (not initial) conditions. What do you mean that the solution of the second equation contradicts the first? How can I check it?

Comment: With Mathematica 13.2.0, `SolJ1[xhat]` gives `0`. (By the way, this is a system of ODEs, not PDEs.)

Comment: Use arbitrary-precision rather than machine precision. `Sol = NDSolve[{OdeM, OdeP, Ic1, Ic2, Ic3, Ic4}, {J1, J2}, {x, -3/10, xhat}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]` Then `And @@ ({Ic1, Ic2, Ic3, Ic4} /. Sol[[1]])` evaluates to `True`